# Combining columns in matrix - python

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I'm trying to do something fairly simple.  Given a matrix, I want to combine the column elements such that:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

...and I want to return:

```
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

This loop might be very simple, but I keep running into iteration errors or index out of range errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `zip()`:

```
zip(*a)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew there had to be a simple method.  My apologies for my ignorance